# Logstash metrics on http response code -> logstash

Tags: logstash, httpresponse, metrics, graylog2

I am trying to do a counter of HTTP response codes using metrics in Logstash. I tried many options but nothing works. I want to send metrics result to Graylog.

I tried this in filter file, using debug mode in logstash I can see 'metrics' buy greylog don't want to present them.

`metrics {
        meter => [ "http.%{HTTP_STATUS_CODE}" ]
        add_tag => [ "metric" ]
        add_field => ["message", "metric test"]
          }`

Comment: Please post what you tried so that people here can see what's wrong and possibly help you

Comment: @MarioTrucco I updated